# Remove Option From Include File In PAM

Tags: kde, login, pam

I use google-authenticator with PAM and it is added in the config file `/etc/pam.d/system-login`. Up until recently I was using Cinnamon and my setup was perfect as I only needed to enter my authentication code once when starting the session, but not for the locked screen. I recently switched to KDE and now cannot unlock the screen. I believe that this is because KDE is trying to also get the authentication code. I found the file `/etc/pam.d/kde` where I believe I could fix this issue. How can I remove the google-authenticator PAM requirement without messing up anything else?

For example something like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth            include         system-login
#auth            remove          pam_google_authenticator.so <== Something to go here

account         include         system-login

password        include         system-login

session         include         system-login
```

Comment: I don't think `remove` is a valid control value. You can just put `#` in front of the line to make it a comment.

Comment: @heemayl Yeah the remove like was just an example of what I want (though making it a comment does make it clearer). I want to just remove the setting. Idk if there is a way to do this

Comment: Ok. Why not put a `#` in front and make the line a comment, or make the result of the module a `optional`: `auth optional pam_google_authenticator.so`

Comment: @heemayl The point is that I want the line to exist in system-login, but then remove that line for a kde login. I have a hacky solution where I just coped and pasted the system-login code and removed the line, but I was wondering if there is something cleaner